# Where to properly apply :hover to keep submenu css in the hover state

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I am trying to make drop down menu. Some folks helped me on 
[CSS only drop down menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314198/css-only-drop-down-menu) post.

Everything works fine except when I hover my mouse to my submenu. The hover state background image in my `#menubar #test2 a:hover` will return to `#menubar #test2 a` state. I really need to get this done and would appreciate if anyone could help me about it. Thanks a million.

My html

```
<ul id="menuBar">
   <li id="test1">test1</li>
   <li id="test2"><a href="#">Pro1</a>
     <div class="subMenu">
        <ul>
           <li><a href="#">sub1</a></li>  
           <li><a href="#">sub2</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">sub3</a></li>
         </ul>
         <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Volleyball</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Walking</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Water Shoes</a></li>
         </ul>
       </div> <!--end of submenu-->
     </li>
  </ul>
```

CSS

```
#menuBar #test2 a{
background:url("../images/btTest.jpg") no-repeat bottom;
display:block;
border-right:1px solid #ffffff;
width:112px;
height:37px;
}

#menuBar #test2 a:hover{
background:url("../images/btTest.jpg") no-repeat top;
}  

#menuBar #test2 a:hover + .subMenu { //submenu show up
display:block;

} 

#menuBar li .subMenu:hover {  //keep submenu show up when hover in submenu
display: block; 
}

//the next one is not working....but I can't think of anything....
#menuBar li .subMenu:hover #menuBar #mens a {  
background:url("../images/btMen.jpg") no-repeat top;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need this:

```
#menuBar #test2 a:hover{
   background:url("../images/btTest.jpg") no-repeat top;
}
```

To be this:

```
#menuBar #test2:hover a {
  background:url("../images/btTest.jpg") no-repeat top;
}
```

To get it to stick when you move to the `.subMenu`. This will not work for IE6 (if you care).

Also these:

```
#menuBar #test2 a:hover + .subMenu { //submenu show up
  display:block;
} 

#menuBar li .subMenu:hover {  //keep submenu show up when hover in submenu
  display: block; 
}
```

Should be able to be replaced with just this:

```
#menuBar li:hover .subMenu {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: very very nice...who would thought a little change of code could change the world....IE6...only 7% of the internet users use that junky browser...not my concern for now.....Thanks a lot.

Comment: on your updated answer. I was wondering #menuBar li:hover .subMenu {
  display: block;
} would make my submenu show up if I hover to #test1. or other li under #menuBar. However, When I tried it, everything worked great. Could you explain it for me?

Comment: No, because the `li` you are hovering over is only one of those `li` elements at any one time, which is what activates the `.subMenu` contained within it.

Comment: I am not quite sure your "li elements at any one time," means. I guess it because #test2 is the only li that has .submenu ??

Comment: Even if every `li` in a list has a `.subMenu`, the only one that will trigger to expose that submenu with the `li:hover` is the *one* element the user is hovering over at the moment, which will only be any one `li` at any one time.