# Submenu list doesnot stay when trying to hover mouse on list items

Tags: css, menu, hover, html-lists

I am new to CSS.
 i am trying to create a Menu like

[image]

and Palletized link has `SubMenu`

[image]

when i hover on `Palletized` link i want to display `SubMenu`. i tried with this [Code](http://jsfiddle.net/4sxna/10/)

But it doesn't give desired output. when i tries to change cursor into my `submenu` it disappears

Comment: please add relevant code in fiddle ...

Comment: Sorry..! See now i have changed..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved disappears issue on your code

here you go: //jsfiddle.net/4sxna/23/

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will solve your issue [Horizontal menu](http://javascriptkit.com/script/script2/csstopmenu.shtml)

Answer (score 0):

See here => http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/dd_valid.html.

Or here: [CSS only drop down menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314198/css-only-drop-down-menu)
(possible dupe)

Answer (score 0):

Check this working **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4sxna/18/)**

Remove display properties from other tags.

Add put the below code in your css:

**CSS**

```
 .SubMenu a
 {display:none;}

 #Menu li:hover>.SubMenu a 
 {display:block;}
```